# Appwrite flutter create email session invalid user credentials

Tags: flutter, appwrite

i've created user  from the admin console of appwrite ,
when I try to create an email session (login) from   client flutter app ,
the response returned   401 invalid credentials, i am sure of every thing is right,
coding or methods

because I've registered the user from client flutter app , and it is working successfully and also when  creating an email session  it login successfully too,

and I've done by mistake login by just mail address from my flutter app it login successfully!

and i discovered after i've edited the user password from appwrite admin console , then trying to login with email and password the response is  401 invalid credentials ...

code example for login method ..

```
     @override
      Future<Either<Failure, Session>> createEmailSession(
          {required String email, required String password}) async {
        Account account = Account(client);
        try {
      
          var res = await account
              .createEmailSession(
                  email: email.toString(), password: password.toString());
               
        
    
          return Right(res);
        } on AppwriteException catch (e) {
           
          return Left(LoginFailure(e.message.toString()));
        }
      }
```

any help can explain what's wrong or misunderstood!

Comment: Before you call `account.createEmailSession()`, please check `client.config['project']`. Is it set to your project ID?

Comment: I did console logged it .. it's correct, the scenario in my question didn't happen with you, or  I am doing something wrong ?

Comment: Perhaps you edited the password for your console account or a user in a different project?

Answer (score 0):

If your email and password values are TextEditingController, you have to change that;
.toString() to .text

```
      var res = await account
          .createEmailSession(
              email: email.toString(), password: password.toString());
```